# How to split a multidimensional array of arrays into multiple single arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, list-comprehension

Consider that I have a large data set that is a multidimensional array `m_array`.

```
m_array[['x', 'y', x],['a', 'b', c] ['1', '2', 3]] <--- x number arrays. Don't know how many.
```

Inside this multi-array I have x number of arrays (smaller data sets) and **I don't know how many arrays** are in the `m_array`

What is the best way to break down `m_array` and extract each array inside it into separate lists.

**So have the following:**

```
a_1['x', 'y', x]

a_2['a', 'b', c]

a_3['1', '2', 3]
```

Comment: Wouldnt it suffice to just loop through it to get individual lists?

Comment: Did you mean to say `m_array = [['x', ... ]]`?

Comment: No I want to extract m_array['[..]', '[...]', ...] into separate lists @DavidZ

Comment: Why do you want them in separate lists?  If it is an unknown number of lists, you will have an unknown number of variables.  Any time you would use `a_1`, you could use `m_array[0]`.  What is the benefit of cluttering your namespace?

Comment: In that case I don't understand what your code means. Lists can't be indexed by strings (as in your comment) or by lists (as in your question). `m_array` is a list, right?

Comment: @zondo The reason is sometimes I'll get multi-array with 1 array other times with 4 arrays etc. I want to test each value inside each array using if statement and for loop to loop through all the arrays. That is which array contains 'x' and which contains 'a' and '1' etc. So I thought splitting it would make it easier but I see your point.

Comment: @DavidZ It is a list. The ' ' was me trying to highlight I want to extract the array. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you going to use variables with dynamic names?
Don't do this. Chances are there are better ways to solve the problem.
If you create dynamically named variables, you don't quite have a good handle to them.

You should use `m_array` directly.

```
In [17]: [print(i) for i in m_array]
['x', 'y', 'x']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['1', '2', 3]
```

Comment: Pay no attention, it is ipython console

Comment: Great! It makes sense. By the way, is there a way getting the n-index int value printed out with the value?

Comment: `[(i,value) for i,value in enumerate(m_array)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
for i in range(len(m_array)):
    exec("a_%d = %s" % (i + 1, repr(m_array[i])))
```